# profiling CUDA on nvidia 3090: "this version of nvprof doesn't support the underlying device"

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

I have installed CUDA toolkit on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, on a system with nvidia rtx 3090 graphics card. and I've successfully compiled and run different code samples. But I haven't managed to run the official profiler tool, `nvprof`. Here is the complete error message I get:

```
======== Warning: This version of nvprof doesn't support the underlying device, GPU profiling skipped
======== Error: application not found.
```

Here is the result of `nvprof --version`:

```
nvprof: NVIDIA (R) Cuda command line profiler
Copyright (c) 2012 - 2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Release version 10.1.243 (21)
```

In case it is relevant, here is the result of `nvcc --versioin`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Is there some compatibility issue between `nvprof` and the latest card from nvidia or Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

**20.04** comes with an old nvprof tool: `nvidia-profiler (10.1.243-3)`

**20.10** comes with a newer one: `nvidia-profiler (11.0.3-1ubuntu1)`

Unfortunately, neither of these is capable of running on a 3000-series card.

Even when you get the 11.2 profiler from [This NVIDIA server](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=debnetwork) that serves deb archives, it will not support it.

Instead, you are expected to run nvidia-nsight-compute to profile your kernel. It seems like command line profiling with nvprof is no longer a thing.

Comment: Note: The same incompatibility occurs for the nvvp (visual profiler) tool.

Answer (score 2):

Bram's answer seems to be correct. Maybe try something like this instead, if you still want to stay in the console:

```
nsys profile -t nvtx,cuda --stats=true --force-overwrite true --wait=all -o my_report ./my_app
```

nsys gives you a nice overview of the kernels and their runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

nvprof does not provide support for graphics cards using Ampere and later architectures. See this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#migrating-to-nsight-tools-from-visual-profiler-and-nvprof).

However, you can use Nsight Systems' compatible syntax to get similar output：

```
nsys nvprof ./myapp
```